# Nginx symfony "invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive"

Tags: symfony, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am working on dockerizing my symfony application, but I cant figure out why the following error occours:

```
web_1  | 2018/09/11 07:21:40 [emerg] 1#1: invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:6
web_1  | nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "try_files" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:6
```

This is my config:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    root /application/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

This is my docker-compose.yml so far:

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
            - ./docker/nginx/default.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template
            - ./:/application
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        links:
            - php
        environment:
            - NGINX_HOST=localhost
            - NGINX_PORT=80
        command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

    php:
        image: php:7.2-fpm
```

Currently I am just trying to get NGINX running without resulting in config errors. I don't expect the symfony application itself to work. Just NGINX combined with PHP-fpm.

Comment: `try_files` does require at least two arguments, but it looks like you have them. Have you tried working with simpler arguments? Like just `index.php /index.php`?

Comment: Yes, I have. When i use a / instead of $uri, it works fine.

Comment: Well, the documentation (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) DOES specify that the first argument needs to be a file. Might be that..

Comment: Somehow it was fixed when i removed the envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf part from the docker-compose.yml

Comment: Also look into http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/vrci/creating-a-dockerised-symfony-application-skeleton

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For anyone finding this question in the future,

If you're using Docker and `envsubst` in your `docker-compose.yml` like the Docker NGINX README tells you to do, that's likely causing the problem. Basically, it is stripping out vars like `$uri` from your NGINX config, leading to errors like this.

There's an issue on it (with the solution) at https://github.com/docker-library/docs/issues/496

## Example:

### Before *(in docker-compose.yml)*:

```
command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

### After:

```
command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$$NGINX_HOST' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```